# Табличный вывод данных из MS SQL в консоль

Tags: c#, консоль, ado.net, вывод

Доброго времени суток,
столкнулся с проблемой вывода результата в табличном представлении в консоль, есть запрос:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@VERSION AS[SQL SERVER VERSION], SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS [ServerName],SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') AS[Server Collation],SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') AS[IsFullTextInstalled],SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly') AS[OnlyOSAuth],SERVERPROPERTY('IsSingleUser') AS[IsSingleUser];", connection);

                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        if (reader.HasRows) // если есть данные
                        {
                            // выводим названия столбцов
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2), reader.GetName(3), reader.GetName(4), reader.GetName(5));



                                while (reader.Read()) // построчно считываем данные
                            {
                                object SQLSERVERVERSION = reader.GetValue(0);
                                object ServerName = reader.GetValue(1);
                                object ServerCollation = reader.GetValue(2);
                                object IsFullTextInstalled = reader.GetValue(3);
                                object OnlyOSAuth = reader.GetValue(4);
                                object IsSingleUser = reader.GetValue(5);

                              Console.WriteLine($"SQLSERVERVERSION={reader[0]}, ServerName={reader[1]}, ServerCollation={reader[2]}, IsFullTextInstalled={reader[3]}, OnlyOSAuth={reader[4]}, IsSingleUser={reader[5]}");
```

В результате вывод происходит таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
что согласитесь не очень информативно

прошу подсказать как настроить табличный или удобно читаемый вывод данных из таблиц, как гипотеза построчный вывод

Comment: Внутри цикла не нужно выводить имена колонок на каждой итерации. Выводите просто данные: `Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4], reader[5]);`

Comment: Так ведь результат тот же.

Comment: Да, убрал построчное. Оставил в таком представлении       Console.WriteLine($"SQLSERVERVERSION={reader[0]}, ServerName={reader[1]}, ServerCollation={reader[2]}, IsFullTextInstalled={reader[3]}, OnlyOSAuth={reader[4]}, IsSingleUser={reader[5]}");